# Python: Scipy confidence interval

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to Python and i wanted to programm a confidence intervall. This is the code i used:

```
conf= st.t.interval(alpha=0.95, df=len(df)-1, loc=np.mean(df_efw).mean(), scale=st.sem(df.stack()))
```

There is actually no problem with the code, it works. However, i found it somewhere but i simply dont understand it. I am using 95% confidence interval, therefore my alpha is 5%. Why do i have to write `alpha = 0.95`?. And why do i have to write `-1` in the `len(df)`. What i also dont understand is the `loc` and `scale`.

Comment: The confidence interval is calculated over a specified multivariate normal distribution - `loc` is the mean of this distribution, `scale` is the standard deviation. The `alpha` is defined as the "inside" of the confidence interval. So if you want to contain 95% of the points, you need `alpha=0.95` (note that `1.00-0.05=0.95`). Regarding the dataframe `df` I cannot help you, since I've never used this function. However, `df=len(df)-1` looks quite weird to me. I would've guessed you need to pass the whole dataframe, not just its length. But then again, I've never used this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the first `df` in `df=len(df)-1` stands for degrees of freedom rather than dataframe. Degrees of freedom is n (the number of observations) - 1 in almost all cases, so that tracks.

I'd recommend going directly to the source and searching the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html) if that's what you're using.